# Why are some JavaFX geometry methods not static for a smaller memory footprint?

Tags: java, javafx

I am just getting into JavaFX but don't really understand why some methods are not static.

For example, the `Point2D` class has a few instance methods, such as `distance(Point2D)`, `angle(Point2D)`, and so on.

Is it logical performance-wise?

I might be wrong, but if I create let's say 1000 objects of the `Point2D` class, there would be 1000 copies in the memory of these instance methods.

If there was one static method, like `Point2D.distance(Point2D p1,Point2D p2)`, it would have one copy in the memory.

Can someone explain why is it this way?

Thanks

Comment: "I might be wrong, but if I create let's say 1000 objects of the Point2D class, there would be 1000 copies in the memory of these instance methods." - that's not how methods work. There isn't a separate copy of each method per instance. Why would there be? What would be different between each copy?

Comment: Note to help you format future questions/answers: [Stack Overflow uses Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, it seems I need to educate myself about the Java Runtime system.

Comment: A method is just a named sequence of code with zero or more inputs and a single output (including `void`, i.e. nothing). That _code_ is the same for all instances of the class, whether the method is static or not. The difference between invocations is the input _values_ and consequently the output _value_, as well as, in the case of instance methods, what instance _state_ (i.e. the _values_ stored in the fields) it can see.

Comment: @Slaw Now I understand, and it is logical, the reason why I asked the question was that I saw some older java code, where there were many such static methods related to geometrical calculations. Perhaps the person who wrote that code thought the same as I did :D And I will have a look at the Markdown syntax. Thanks

Comment: The class of static methods you saw was mostly likely a design choice. My guess is the class was a "utility" class, similar to `java.util.Arrays`, `java.util.Collections`, `java.nio.file.Files` and so on.

Comment: Iirc it's not defined how a jre is implemented, so there *could* be a implementation that does that. However I would be shocked, if this was actually implemented like this in any jre. In general object oriented languages threat a non-static  method `T1 m(T2 a, T3 b, ...)` in an object `A` similar to a static method with the signature `T1 m(A o, T2 a, T3 b, ...)` and make sure the object itself is passed accessed, when non-static members are referenced...